# get groups with any of desired values

Tags: python, performance, pandas, unique, pandas-groupby

```
gr = []
for i in range(12000): gr.extend([i] * 2)
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'gr': gr,
                   'col1': np.random.choice(200, 24000)})
anyOfThese = np.array([50, 60]) #randomly chosen
t = time()
out = df[df.groupby('gr')['col1'].transform(lambda x: np.any(np.in1d(np.array(x), anyOfThese))).astype(bool)].gr.unique()
print(round(time() - t,2))
>>> 1.87
```

I need to get all the groups that have any of the two wanted values in `col1`.

Is there a way to achieve this faster? I need to repeat the same process ~100k times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filtering by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
out = df.loc[df['col1'].isin(anyOfThese), 'gr'].unique()
```

Or check membership by [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
out = df.loc[np.in1d(df['col1'], anyOfThese), 'gr'].unique()
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(218)

gr = []
for i in range(12000): 
    gr.extend([i] * 2)
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'gr': gr,
                   'col1': np.random.choice(200, 24000)})
anyOfThese = np.array([50, 60]) #randomly chosen

a = df[df.groupby('gr')['col1'].transform(lambda x: np.any(np.in1d(np.array(x), anyOfThese))).astype(bool)].gr.unique()
out = df.loc[df['col1'].isin(anyOfThese), 'gr'].unique()
print ((a == out).all())
True
```

---

```
In [314]: %timeit df[df.groupby('gr')['col1'].transform(lambda x: np.any(np.in1d(np.array(x), anyOfThese))).astype(bool)].gr.unique()
2.9 s ± 79.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [315]: %timeit df.loc[df['col1'].isin(anyOfThese), 'gr'].unique()
746 µs ± 32.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [316]: %timeit df.loc[np.in1d(df['col1'], anyOfThese), 'gr'].unique()
325 µs ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Amazing how simplicity is overlooked sometimes and things get over-complicated for no reason

Answer (score 1):

For larger arrays, if you have just 2 values, you can check for equality of each and use the `|` (or) condition:

```
%timeit df.loc[(df['col1'].values == 50) | (df['col1'].values == 60), 'gr'].unique()
%timeit df.loc[np.in1d(df['col1'], anyOfThese), 'gr'].unique()

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ms per loop
```

Tested on Numpy 1.11.3 / Pandas 0.19.2 / Python 3.6.0. Performance may vary depending on your setup. Code used for testing:

```
gr = []
for i in range(120000): gr.extend([i] * 2)

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'gr': gr,
                   'col1': np.random.choice(200, 240000)})

anyOfThese = np.array([50, 60])

%timeit df.loc[(df['col1'].values == 50) | (df['col1'].values == 60), 'gr'].unique()
%timeit df.loc[np.in1d(df['col1'], anyOfThese), 'gr'].unique()
```